# Regex Query Help - Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

This is somewhat related to: [Regular Expression - Formatting text in a block - IM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278728/regular-expression-formatting-text-in-a-block-im) but a different problem.

Looking for `-`'s wrapping text with the following conditions:

Conditions:

- token can be at start or end of line
- token must be surround by space or one or more symbols: {.,!@#$....}.

  - must not be a normal character [a-zA-Z] surrounding the `-` pair in question.
  - See Sample test 3 ...w-thank you-
  - Test 4 and 5 succeed because the `-` is wrapped with [^a-zA-Z]
- token must not be followed by a space on the first `-` or a space preceding the last `-`

  - "-Wow -" will not be a match as the closing `-` was preceded by a space.
  - See Sample test 6 and 7

For the front of the regular expression I would need: `(^|[\s\W]+)`
and the end would be: `($|[\s\W]+)`

I have the current expression, but it is failing due to the escape condition being stop after finding the first `-`

```
   (^|[\s\W]+)-([^\s][^-]*)-($|[\s\W]+)
```

Sample test strings would be:

1. (all.): `-Wow-thank you-.`
2. (Wow): `-Wow- thank you-!`
3. (NIL): `- Wow-thank you-.`
4. (thank you): `- Wow!-thank you-`
5. (thank you): `- Wow -thank you-`
6. (all): `-Wow - thank you-`
7. (NIL): `-Wow - thank you -`

Does this require look behind? (I'm a regex newbie so please bear with me)  Or is my middle condition totally wrong.

Thank you much!
mwolfe.

Comment: I don't understand your 1st comment after your 2nd condition.

Comment: Example 3 fails by this condition because there is a character "w" before the "-thank you-".  If that character was a space or a symbol then "-thank you-" would have been identified/flagged/found.  That is why Example 4 work because the character before the "-" was a "!"

Comment: +1 - Very nice attempt, especially for a (self-proclaimed) newbie.

Comment: Some unrelated pointers, though you may already know. (1) Beware that the `\w` class includes the underscore and numbers! It may be better to use `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. (2) You can invoke case-insensitive matching by using the `/.../i` modifier, thereby only needing to write `[a-z]` or `[a-z0-9]`. (3) Beware that the universe of characters isn't limited to letters, numbers, and symbols. You say the tokens have to be surrounded by a space or one or more symbols. But then you say, as if equivalently, that it must not be surrounded by `[a-zA-Z]`. These are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simpler middle expression.

```
(^|[\s\W]+)-(.*?)-($|[\s\W]+)
             ^^^
```

The non-greedy wildcard match would capture the minimum string necessary to match the following `-($|[\s\W]+)`.

---

**Edit.** Okay, I see why that's wrong. You want a non-space character to immediately follow and succeed the opening and closing dashes, respectively. So try this:

```
(^|[\s\W]+)-(\S.*?\S)-($|[\s\W]+)
             ^^   ^^
```

Comment: Way better. But it doesn't capture test #6

Comment: You sure? Works for me: http://rubular.com/r/xhXidunhmF. Unless I'm misunderstanding your example.

Comment: Thank you!!!!  Your link on rubular is more advanced in your first post.  Thanks for rubular; been testing using regex101.com

Comment: Oh, you must not have seen the edit that I made; try refreshing the page. Sorry about the initial answer. And you're welcome!

Comment: But yes, what you suggested would have worked as well. You probably meant to put the `[^\s]`s inside the capturing group though.

Comment: I'm so grateful.  Thank you so much acheong87.