# Kendo UI editor and reset.css

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, editor

How can I prevent the reset.css from clearing out the bold or italic style formats in the kendo editor? since, I need reset.css for other parts of the applications.

Comment: Include reset.css before your kendo css files

Comment: I already included the reset.css first in the order. it didn't help.

Comment: How is the bold / italic style applied? Which control? Can we have a screenshot? How do you include kendo's control? What have you tried?

Comment: If i remove the :font: inherit;" from the reset.css it leaves the bold text. Do I need to overwrite the font related settings?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/senthu/PJq3w/ You can check this one here. When I add the reset.css it is not doing the bold on the text. Basically reset removes the style.

Comment: Yep, you'll have to override it. Have you tried a different reset CSS like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why reset.css wants to change "font" to "inherit" on strong elements but it is not very logic. Kendo editor uses   to make text bold so it creates a conflict.

Add this CSS

```
strong { font-weight: bold }
```

or

```
strong { font-weight: bold!important }
```

or use another reset css like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

For more information, take a look at this SO question: [YUI Reset CSS Makes <strong><em>this not work</em></strong>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107/yui-reset-css-makes-strongemthis-not-work-em-strong)