# No bold text with short-hand font property

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was reading that **font weight** is an *optional* value in the **Short-Hand Font Property**. Yet, if I don't state it, it will make everything `font-weight: normal`, including `strong` and *heading* elements. Can someone clarify this for me.

```css
* {
  font: 100%/1.3 serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading one</h1>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Another paragraph, with <b>bold</b> and <strong>strong</strong>.</p>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/accidental-css-resets/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107/yui-reset-css-makes-strongemthis-not-work-em-strong

Comment: I noticed that using `body { }` instead of `* { }` actually lets your heading, bold and strong elements become bold as they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shorthand font, the `font-size` and `font-family` are required. Everything else is optional. However, the values omitted will be set to their *initial* values, which in most cases is “normal”, as against “bold”. This is the case with headings, and strong and bold tags as well.